# DXA 1.6 website: Error: No matching Localization found for the image url

Tags: web8, dxa, dxa-1.6

I changed the value for Images Path and Images URL to `\media\mysite` and `/media/mysite/` in the Publication properties and re-published my custom page and publish setting page.

But now its not rendering the images on the webpage, when I copied the image url from page source and open it in new tab it gives error:

> No matching Localization found for URL http://{domain}/media/mysite/{image-name}.png.

Is there any additional step I need to do apart from re-publishing the custom page and publish settings page?

Comment: What is the Publication URL?

Answer (score 3):

The settings are cached agressively in the DXA Web App. If you change/republish the settings, you either have to restart your DXA Web App or use the `/admin/refresh` URL to flush the cache.

Furthermore, if you change the Images/Multimedia URL on your Publication, you will have to republish all Binaries (because their URLs change).

Comment: I do have unpublished all the pages and restarted the WebApp but still same error there. Also all my components are embedded in page itself and gets published with page only. If I am changing back the "Images Path" and "Images URL" to "\media" and "/media/" in the Publication properties it is then working fine and rendering the Images on webpage. Is there any reason it is forcing me to use the default values only ?

Comment: No, it should work fine with non-default values (we are doing that in our automated tests).